# How to modify Cache-Control setting in HttpResponse

Tags: asp.net-mvc, httpresponse, browser-cache, aspnetboilerplate

My ASPNET Zero alway reload all css and js files instead of using cache. That is the reason it was too slow. So how can I change this setting value?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the reason, the ASPNET Zero disable Client cache by default. My solution is just commented a line of code as below

```
protected override void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    base.Application_BeginRequest(sender, e);
    //DisableClientCache();
}

private void DisableClientCache()
{
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.Cache.SetExpires(CacheExpireDate);
    Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `asp-append-version="true"` to the `script` or `link` tags in the razor pages where your css/js files are included.

Abp does provide dynamic scripts which are created at runtime creation. As such, there are limitations to what you can cache as discussed at https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/3673